# Alternate rows background color in a group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc, rdl

I have following situation:

Report with nested groups, whether group column has value 1 or 2. Next child group has 2 groups for each parent group, so for parent group 1 there is two child groups (1-1 and 1-3), and also for parent group 2 I have two child groups (2-2 and 2-4).

My question is, how to set color to `WhiteSmoke` for rows from 1-1, and color `White` for rows from 1-3, and again `WhiteSmoke` for 2-2 and `White` for 2-4.

If there is order like 1, 2, 3, ..., then will be easy with using `Mod` operator, but my order is 1, 3, 2, 4 and i cannot find algorithm for alternating color

**EDITED**

[image]

Comment: please provide some screenshot, it is **very** difficult to understand your question

Comment: please verify the following: assuming this is the order: `1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8...` you want to color only `3,4,7,8..` ?

Comment: @GilPeretz Yes, something like that way, and you can also see sample on my pictures I uploaded

Comment: that what I thought :), see my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.

```
=IIF(RunningValue("NameofGrouptoAlternateColor", CountDistinct, "NameofParentGroup") Mod 2, "White", "Wheat")
```

This worked for me and I think it's what the original poster was trying to accomplish.

Comment: This worked for me after I changed "NameofGrouptoAlternateColor" to "Fields!NameOfFieldToGroupOn.Value". In other words, it didn't work when I used the group name but it did work when I used the underlying field from the Group expression.

Answer (score 3):

```
=IIF(RunningValue(Fields!FieldToGroupOn.Value, CountDistinct, "ParentGroupName") Mod 2, "LightGrey", "Transparent")
```

Where:

`FieldToGroupOn` is the field in the dataset you are grouping on and wish to produce alternating colors.

`ParentGroupName` is the **name** of the row group in the tablix that is the parent of the group you wish to alternate colors for.

Comment: You are pretty close to final solution,except one thing. If my first parent group has even number of child groups, then coloring will be `Color1:Color2:Color1:Color2` and in next parent group coloring will follow same patern `Color1:Color2:Color1:Color2`. But, if first parent group has three child groups, then coloring will be `Color1:Color2:Color1` and in next parent group `Color1:Color2:Color1`, which means that last child group from previous parent group and first child group in next parent group have same coloring that gives little odd coloring scheme.

Answer (score 1):

assuming that this is the order: `1,3,2,4,5,7,6,8...` you want to color only `3,4,7,8..`

Then the expression should be:

```
=iif(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 4 <> 0 AND
 ((RowNumber(Nothing)+1) Mod 4 <> 0), "White", "WhiteSmoke")
```

[image]

Comment: still color all rows, from 1 till 4

Comment: I super duper duble checked it , try now :P

Comment: Hm, now is 1, 2, 3 colored in one color, and 4 is different

Comment: That wired , I even attached my result. can you show me the table's structure ?

Comment: I found problem why your solution not worked for me. Sample i gave in question is just sample, and I didn't realize that till now. In rel solution, number of rows in one group can differ from other groups, and your solution is strictly connected with number of rows. Maybe to change logic to work with group number (1, 2, 3, 4)

Comment: Replace `Nothing` with the Group Name.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly you want to alternate colors on "group change".
If so, this is the solution:

```
IIf(RowNumber("TheNameOfYourGroup") Mod 2 = 0, "White", "WhiteSmoke")
```

That's the expression you use for your `Background Color` property.

Comment: This code colors last two groups, into one color, but I need to color odd groups into one color, and even into other color. But, when I say odd even, I don't think about values placed into groups, but groups position, like first group, second group, third....

Comment: This code works if I reference to values inside group field, but I need to relate to group position, if I explain well

Comment: I think I didn't understand. At what level are you placing this expressions? Inside the group, outside the group? Can post a picture with your current layout and highlight where the expression is?

Answer (score 1):

I've forced to use custom code to achieve your goal, here is my solution:

Custom code section

```
Public Shared ReverseLookup = True
Public Function GetColor(ByVal currentValue As Integer, ByVal previosValue As Integer) As String
    If ReverseLookup = True
        If currentValue = previosValue Then
                GetColor = "Gray"
        Else
                GetColor = "Green"
                ReverseLookup = False
        End If
    Else
        If currentValue = previosValue Then
                GetColor = "Green"
        Else
                GetColor = "Gray"
                ReverseLookup = True
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

And in the BackgroundColor property :

```
=Code.GetColor(Fields!secondid.Value, Previous(Fields!secondid.Value))
```

input parameters are current secondid value (value from paren group of details) and previos secondid value.

And here my result:
I believe that it is exactly what you need :)

[image]

Comment: I need to color group secondid(1) and all related rows in white, and group secondid(3) with related rows in whitesmoke, same again for group secondid(2) in white and secondid(4) in whitesmoke. But one thing to notice is that number of rows in one group can vary from number of rows in other groups. I need somehow to reference to group  row number, or something similar.

Comment: Soryy, I didn't get you (My bad). I've updated my answer with new solution.

Comment: I didn't yet tested, but bravo, you understand my need :) Picture is that I want